# WordPress - Como inserir custom_fields ao inserir a publicação via API v2?

Tags: wordpress

Estou adicionando publicações em meu site WordPress através da API v2. A publicação está sendo inserida, porém os custom_fields não estão. Segue abaixo o meu payload:

```
$data = [
    'title'         => 'Meu novo titulo 03',
    'status'        => 'publish',
    'meta_data'     => [
        [
            'key' => 'bt_thumb',
            'value' => '111'
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'embed_code',
            'value' => '222'
        ],
    ]
];
```

Ele não da erro nenhum, simplesmente não insere o custom_field (os custom_fields já existem cadastrados no WP, segue imagem abaixo).
[image: Custom fields existentes no WP]

Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Então, meu apelo era para uma solução que não seja necessário utilizar plugin, todavia, no momento achei essa solução qual estou utilizando.
Agradeço a todos e espero que possa ajudar pessoas com esse problema no futuro.
Resolução: https://medium.com/@albertoaguiarneto/adicao-custom-fields-wordpress-usando-api-v2-fe77a933e378